# How to pass the global variable from one Test class to another test class and select that value in a dropdown in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, ui-automation, page-factory

**I have this class ( DoctorRegistrationTest.java ) and having the global variable doctorCode , doctorFirstName , doctorFamilyName )**

```
@BeforeMethod(groups = {"BVT", "Regression"})
public void loadRmsPage() {
    loadRmsProfile();
    softAssert = new SoftAssert();
    doctorRegistrationPage = new DoctorRegistrationPage(webDriver);
}

@Epic("RMS - Create Doctor")
@Feature("RMS - Create Doctor functionality")
@Story("AUT-688")
@Severity(SeverityLevel.BLOCKER)
@Test(description = "Positive : Doctor Creation  ", groups = {"BVT", "Regression"})
public void createDoctorTestMethod() {
    do {
        doctorCode = String.valueOf(generateRandomNumber(1000, 9999));
    } while (false && doctorRegistrationPage.verifyCreatedDoctor(doctorCode));

    setDoctorRegistrationInformation();
    createDoctor();
}

public void createDoctor() {
    doctorRegistrationPage.loadDoctorRegistrationPage();
    doctorRegistrationPage.fillDoctorNameInformation(doctorCode, doctorFirstName, doctorFamilyName, doctorFirstNameInArabic, doctorFamilyNameInArabic);
    doctorRegistrationPage.fillDoctorGeneralInformation(dateOfBirth, joinDate, identityNo, expiryDate, gender, doctorTitle, employmentType, identityType);
    doctorRegistrationPage.fillDoctorContactInformation(mobileNumber, companyEmail);
    doctorRegistrationPage.fillDoctorOtherInformation(doctorInformationEnglish, doctorInformationArabic);
    doctorRegistrationPage.fillDoctorTiming(followUpDays, slotDurationMinutes);
    doctorRegistrationPage.fillDoctorHospitalsAndClinics(hospital, clinics);
    doctorRegistrationPage.fillDoctorDefaultProcedure(defaultProcedur, consultationProcedure);
    boolean result = doctorRegistrationPage.verifyCreatedDoctor(doctorCode);
    LOG.info("Return value of verifyCreatedDoctor method " + result);
    softAssert.assertTrue(result, "TEST FAILED - CREATED DOCTOR NOT LISTING IN THE GRID");
    softAssert.assertAll();
    doctorRegistrationPage.logOutUser();
}

public void setDoctorRegistrationInformation() {
    readPropertiesFile();
    setNames();
    setNumberValues();
    setDate();
}

public void setNames() {
    doctorFirstName = "AUT DN " + getRandomStringName(4);
    doctorFamilyName = "AUT DFN " + getRandomStringName(4);
    companyEmail = getRandomStringName(5) + "@aut.com";
    doctorInformationEnglish = getRandomStringName(6);
}



public String getRandomStringName(int randomStringLength) {
    return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(randomStringLength).toLowerCase();
}

public int generateRandomNumber(int low, int high) {
    return (new Random()).nextInt(high - low) + low;
}
```

}

**I have another class ( DoctorScheduleTest.java ) and needs to pass doctorCode , doctorFirstName , doctorFamilyName from (DoctorRegistrationTest.java ) to doctorSchedulePage.selectDoctorDropdown(doctor); method, instead of hardcoding the detail. Must pass the value like this (" doctorCode: doctorFirstName doctorFamilyName )**

```
private String doctor =" 8938: AUT DN gvgl AUT DFN wnrn ";


@BeforeMethod(groups = {"BVT", "Regression"})
public void loadRmsPage()
{
    loadRmsProfile();
    softAssert = new SoftAssert();
    doctorSchedulePage = new DoctorSchedulePage(webDriver);
}

@Epic("RMS")
@Feature("RMS - Create Doctor Schedule functionality")
@Story("AUT-835")
@Severity(SeverityLevel.BLOCKER)
@Test(description = "Positive : Doctor Schedule Creation", groups = {"BVT", "Regression"})
public void doctorScheduleCreationTestMethod()
{
    setTemplateName();
    createInitialSchedule();
    setSchedule();
    saveTemplate();
    setTemplate();
    setDateRange();
    generateSchedule();
}

public void createInitialSchedule()
{
    doctorSchedulePage.loadDoctorScheduleDashboard();
    doctorSchedulePage.selectHospitalDropDown(hospital);
    doctorSchedulePage.selectClinicDropDown(clinic);
    doctorSchedulePage.selectDoctorDropdown(doctor);
    doctorSchedulePage.fillTemplate(scheduleTemplateName);
}

public void setSchedule()
{
    doctorSchedulePage.sundaySchedule(startHourTime,startMinuteTime,startSchedule,endHourTime,endMinuteTime,endSchedule);
    doctorSchedulePage.mondaySchedule(startHourTime,startMinuteTime,startSchedule,endHourTime,endMinuteTime,endSchedule);
    doctorSchedulePage.tuesdaySchedule(startHourTime,startMinuteTime,startSchedule,endHourTime,endMinuteTime,endSchedule);
    doctorSchedulePage.wednesdaySchedule(startHourTime,startMinuteTime,startSchedule,endHourTime,endMinuteTime,endSchedule);
    doctorSchedulePage.thursdaySchedule(startHourTime,startMinuteTime,startSchedule,endHourTime,endMinuteTime,endSchedule);
    doctorSchedulePage.fridaySchedule(startHourTime,startMinuteTime,startSchedule,endHourTime,endMinuteTime,endSchedule);
    doctorSchedulePage.saturdaySchedule(startHourTime,startMinuteTime,startSchedule,endHourTime,endMinuteTime,endSchedule);
}

public void saveTemplate()
{
    doctorSchedulePage.saveTemplate();
}

public void setTemplate()
{
    doctorSchedulePage.selectTemplateDropdown(scheduleTemplateName);
}

public void setDateRange()
{
    doctorSchedulePage.selectScheduleDate(scheduleStartDate,scheduleEndDate);
}

public void generateSchedule()
{
    doctorSchedulePage.generateSchedule();
}

public int generateRandomNumber(int low, int high)
{
    return (new Random()).nextInt(high - low) + low;
}

public void setTemplateName()
{
    scheduleTemplateName = "Template " + getRandomStringName(3);
}

public String getRandomStringName(int randomStringLength)
{
    return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(randomStringLength).toLowerCase();
}
```

}

**DoctorSchedulePage.java ( selectDoctorDropdown method )**

```
public void selectDoctorDropdown(String doctorcode)
{
    selectValueFromDropDown(doctorDropdown, doctorcode);
}
```

**BasePage.java (selectValueFromDropDown method )**

protected void selectValueFromDropDown(WebElement element, String value) {
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {

```
        waitForElementToPresent(element);

        Select dropdown = new Select(element);

        LOG.info("Selected "+value);

        dropdown.selectByVisibleText(value);   
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question indicates, that you have an issue with passing a test data into tests. That should be addressed in the first place.

Since that is another topic (and a much bigger one) I would recommend a *workaround*, using a separate class, with a doctor's data.

```
public static class Doctor{
 public static String FirstName;
 public static String FamilyName;
```

Initialize the data in the setup and use is whenever you need.

As I said before, that is not the best solution, as testing data *should* be kept outside of the tests, but might be helpful for now.

Comment: Is there anyway to pass the values ( FirstName, FamilyName ) from DoctorRegistrationTest.java to DoctorScheduleTest.java select method, other than creating a new class

Comment: If you are storing first name and family name in the fields of the DoctorRegistrationTest class then you could get it with the help of getters.